# JqGrid's Row selected by default

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I want to set a jqgrid's row by default and to do something with this event. is  it possible ? I'm workin' with asp.net (C#)  and Json

Answer (score 3):

You can use [setSelection](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method of the jqGrid to select a row. The bast place to do this is inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event. You can use [getDataIDs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method or just use `data` parameter of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events). In case of usage of the standard `jsonReader` in `data.rows` you have the array of rows send from the server and `data.rows[iRow].id` is the id if the row with the 0-based index `iRow`. The exact format of `data` parameter of the method [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) depends on the `datatype` of jqGrid which you use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar, and I'm getting some very odd results.

For one thing, the checkbox associated with the default items isn't selected.

For another, in Firebug, it shows that the aria-selected class for the enclosing row tag is set to TRUE! Click the checkbox, and it puts a check in the box while setting the aria-selected class to false... which is the opposite of what happens with the other rows.

Well, we figured out the cause of the odd behavior: indexes can't have spaces in them.