# jqgrid select rows by default based on column value

Tags: jqgrid

As an extension to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031936/jqgrid-custom-edit-behavior-for-one-column), I would like to automatically select rows by default. In [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531957/jqgrids-row-selected-by-default), they use loadComplete to select rows after server request. However, I request from the server once and use local data from then on. I need instead to reselect rows every time the columns are organized, the grid is searched...basically every time the view of the data changes.

I select rows based on a column (book_id) rather than an explicit rowid, so would the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781900/jqgrid-search-a-value-on-the-grid/3783086#3783086) be appropriate? Or does jqGrid have an explicit method (`onUpdateGrid`, e.g.) to help achieve this goal? It looks for now that I would just have to replicate code under both `onPaging` and `onSortCol`.

The dataInit method for the fav_books column:

```
initBookEdit: function(elem){
  //populate reference table
  populateBookRefs($(elem).val());

  //display dialog which contains reference table
  //pressing OK button on dialog saves all id's as a
  //comma delimited list in the main table
  $('#bookRefPopup').dialog({
     buttons: {
    "OK": function(){
        var selectedRows = bookRefTable.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
        var selectedIds = new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<selectedRows.length; i++){
            var changedRow = bookRefTable.getRowData(selectedRows[i]);
            var book_id = changedRow['book_id'];
            selectedIds.push(book_id);
        }
        var editedRow = $('#mainTable').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        $('#mainTable').jqGrid('setCell',editedRow, 'docs_ref', selectedIds, null, null, true);
        $('#mainTable').trigger('reloadGrid');
        $(this).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
}//close buttons
  });//close dialog
}
```

And the initialization of the reference table:

```
function populateBookRefs(ids){
  values = ids.split(',');
  grid.jqGrid({
     ...
     loadComplete:  function(){ //event executed after server request
        for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
          grid.jqGrid('setSelection',values[i],true);
        }

    }
     ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like [gridComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) will do what i want:

```
gridComplete: function(){   
    var grid_ids=grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for(var i=0; i<grid_ids.length; i++){
        var rowid = grid_ids[i];
        var aRow = grid.jqGrid('getRowData',rowid);
        var book_id = aRow['book_id'];
        if($.inArray(book_id,values)!=-1){
            grid.jqGrid('setSelection',rowid,true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The enumeration of all rows like you do (with respect of `getDataIDs`) will work very slow in case of many rows. Look at  [the another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664587/jqgrid-load-large-data-set-without-pagination/5690583#5690583). There show much more effective way of enumeration. You should just change the setting of `ui-state-disabled` class to call of `setSelection``which you need.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to catch a potential problem. Much appreciated!

Comment: wait, now i have the problem that gridComplete never finishes, because _index is the object {undefined:99}, so I can never get rowData and start selecting things. could this be a local data problem?

Comment: If you include the test data which you use and include more full JavaScript code I could try to help you. To be able to do this I should have enough data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: are there any hosts for jqgrid so i can create a fiddle?